# Is the keyword 'this' needed when instantiating a new inner class?

Tags: java

Another example from the Oracle Java SE tutorials. It works fine, but I'm not sure if/why 'this' is necessary when creating an instance of the inner class. The result seems to be same regardless of whether I take it out or not.

To be clear, I am referring to:
        InnerEvenIterator iterator = this.new InnerEvenIterator(); // not sure why using 'this'

```
public class DataStructure {
    // create an array

    private final static int SIZE = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

    public DataStructure() {
        // fill the array with ascending integer values
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void printEven() {
        // prints out the value of even indices in the array
        InnerEvenIterator iterator = this.new InnerEvenIterator(); // not sure why using 'this'
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.getNext() + " ");
        }
    }

    // inner class implements the Iterator pattern
    private class InnerEvenIterator {
        // start stepping through the array from the beginning

        private int next = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            // check if a current element is the last in the array
            return (next <= SIZE - 1); // -1 b/c dealing with array's length.
        }

        public int getNext() {
            // record a value of an even index of the array
            int retValue = arrayOfInts[next];
            // get the next even element
            next += 2;
            return retValue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        // fill the array with integer values and print out only
        // values of even indices
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
        ds.printEven();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a `this.`, in this case. However, an inner class must always be constructed using an enclosing instance, so the `this.` simply makes this clear to the reader.

If you're not inside of a non-static method of `DataStructure` (i.e., if `this` does not exist, or else isn't an instance of `DataStructure`), then you must actually specify an instance of `DataStructure` when creating an `InnerEvenIterator`:

```
InnerEvenIterator iterator = dataStructure.new InnerEvenIterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a point to correct answers mentioned above:

When you have a function, let's say `setInnerEvenIterator(InnerEvenIterator)`, as follows

```
class DataStructure {

    InnerEvenIterator iterator;

    public void setInnerEvenIterator(InnerEvenIterator iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }
}
```

then you need to specify `this` keyword to rectify the possible conflict that may arise due to same argument and instance name. So `this.someThing` represents instance variable of the class. If you do not explicitly provide one  it is OK as long as there is no conflicting situation arising out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Non-static inner classes are bound to the enclosing outer class's instance.

Extending on the idea that an *inner class is dependent on the outer class.*

- *Static inner class, just like all other static resources, belongs to the Outer Class.*
- *Non-Static inner class, just like all other non-static resources, belongs to 'this' instance of the Outer Class.*

Now its just for readability if you decide to use 'this' in case Outer Class's instance is available by default.

Example:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass in = new OuterClass.InnerClass(); //static inner
OuterClass.InnerClass in = outerClass.new InnerClass(); //non- static inner
// outerClass is an instance of OuterClass
```

Comment: A "static inner class" is properly termed a _nested class_. Properly speaking, an _inner class_ is non-static, by definition.